# Multimedia keys not working in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: keyboard, 19.10, multimedia, kodi

I recently updated from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 and noticed the multimedia keys such as Play and Stop stopped working in Kodi. Whenever I press a multimedia key, it only shows a big crossed circle icon (also in desktop). I tried to enable/disable the shortcuts for the multimedia keys, but it didn't work. I also cannot create a new shortcut with the multimedia keys, because the big icon already appears when pressing the key. I'm no more sure if I had to disable or enable the shortcuts in 19.04 though.

I'm not sure, if it is related, but the Ubuntu upgrade finished not clean. It ended  in console and I had to reset my PC. However everything seems to work correctly besides the multimedia keys.

Any help would be appretiated.

Comment: A definitive test would be to boot from a LiveUSB made from a 19.04 ISO and testing for multimedia key function; then, repeat the test with a LiveUSB made from a 19.10 ISO. Please run those tests, and let us know the result by clicking [edit] and adding the results to your question.

Comment: @K7AAY I'm also having this issue. I also upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10 but my upgrade worked just fine. The media keys used to work fine on 19.04 and they also work on the live USB for 19.10.

Comment: @Topo 
Not sure if this also applies in this case, but try language support (from menu) -> input method -> change from Ibus to none, restart. Not a fix, but at least a work around. Please mention if it works. If it does, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: It didn't work for me @JacobVlijm :(
Radim did it work for you?

Comment: Shoot @Topo, sorry to hear.

Comment: @Topo your suggestion does not work in my case either.

Comment: Hi, I'm also affected by this issue after a **clean** install of Ubuntu 19.10. Sad to know there is no workaround so far. :-(

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: at least in my case this is happening because Google Chrome is capturing media keys!
Two possible fixes:
**/1/** [Disable capturing in Chrome](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/04/17/fix-chrome-blocking-keyboard-multimedia-keys-from-working/)
--- **/2/** Open Rythmbox *before* and Chrome *afterwards* (this way you are still able to control Youtube with media keys)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug/a missing issue of the new software.

---

It is not an issue with **detecting** multimedia keys but with **connecting** the key function with the action.

That is, the desktop recognizes multimedia key (as it shows the *ban* symbol) and could perform that action (play, stop, next, etc.) but there is not **target** in which direct it (there is no application **registered**).

Ultimately, with the upgrade, some component of the desktop does not act more as **connector** and this id the reason why your fix do not work

> enable/disable the shortcuts [...] didn't work

---

*look for **mpris** if you want to grow your knowledge*

Comment: Any tips to get it working again?

Comment: Try to open a bug upstream to understand if it was intentional or it is a bug

Comment: This thread may also be relevant to your purpose: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186160/prevent-mpris-from-recognizing-an-application